# Share 100% between 4 range inputs by taking into account the value of each range for sharing the remaining %

Tags: javascript, math, percentage

I have 4 inputs and I'm trying to share their values in equity depending on their previous value.

What I am trying to achieve is if for instance I have one field at 50% another one at 25%, the remaining fields will be at 12.5%
If I have two fields at 29.75% and one at 39.5% the last one will be at 1%
if I have one field at 75% and one at 20% the others will be at 2.5%
and so on.

Here is what I've tried so far unsuccessfully:

```js
let ranges = [a,b,c,d];
let old_value = 1;

for(let rang of ranges)
{
    rang.onfocus=(e)=>{
    old_value=parseInt(e.target.value);
  }
    rang.onchange=(e)=>{
    console.log(old_value);
    let sortedRanges = ranges.filter(el=>el.name!=e.target.name);
    for(let cur of sortedRanges)
        cur.value-= (parseInt(e.target.value) - old_value)/4;
    old_value = e.target.value;
  }
}
```

```html
<input name="a" id="a" type="range" value="25" min="1" max="100"/>
<input name="b" id="b" type="range" value="25" min="1" max="100"/>
<input name="c" id="c" type="range" value="25" min="1" max="100"/>
<input name="d" id="d" type="range" value="25" min="1" max="100"/>
```

I've also tried to look into scale, for instance if I have one field that was previously at 25 and is now at 40 that represents a scale factor of 1.6 but havn't figured out how this could be useful.

Also the much simpler approach of simply dividing the remaining percent to share by 3 does not cut it as if another field as a different value there is no regular ratio between the three remaining field.

Advices.

Comment: do you have an example for four ranges? what if i change (all 25) the first to 50?

Comment: how to find which field needs to change?

Comment: @User863 that's à good question, I thought there could be à math formula just taking into account the total of all fields and redistributing it. like secondfield= value * remainingpercenttoshare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const ranges = [a,b,c,d];
ranges.forEach(rangeElement => {
  rangeElement.addEventListener('change', ({target: { value } }) => {
    rangeElement.setAttribute('value', (+value).toFixed(2));
    const rangeIndex = ranges.indexOf(rangeElement)
    const previousRanges = ranges.slice(0, rangeIndex);
    const nextRanges = ranges.slice(rangeIndex + 1);
    const sumOfPrevious = +value + previousRanges.reduce((acc, {value}) => acc + +value, 0)
    const valueOfRest = ((100 - sumOfPrevious) / nextRanges.length).toFixed(2)
    nextRanges.forEach(range => range.setAttribute('value', valueOfRest));
  })
})
```

```css
input::after {
  content: attr(value);
}
```

```html
<input name="a" id="a" type="range" value="25" min="1" max="100"/>
<input name="b" id="b" type="range" value="25" min="1" max="100"/>
<input name="c" id="c" type="range" value="25" min="1" max="100"/>
<input name="d" id="d" type="range" value="25" min="1" max="100"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I might be able to do something with that. My only problem remaining is what if the field that has 100% is the third one or the fourth one ?

Comment: I modified the snippet to show the percentages. For the use case you're asking for just see what it does above. If doens't do what you want add if statement to handle those cases the way you want

Comment: There is something not quite right, you can have 4 fields at 100%

Comment: @codeanjero You'll have to update the `max` attribute of the `nextRanges` to prevent that .